# visual studio code *.jsx file emmet snippet

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, emmet

I cannot get emmet snippet work on jsx files on my vs code. When I write jsx html code I want div to give me  but I just cannot get it to work even when I changed the emmet config files to "jsx": "html".

Answer (score 0):

You should put in your user config file as follows.

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
  "javascript": "javascriptreact"
}
```